# Contract Management

Tags: contract-manager

I'd like to track various contracts (at work).

There are service contracts for CNC machines, maintenance contracts from software vendors as well as various other contracts in purchasing and HR.

I imagine that the contract data (partner, begin, end, notice period, the scanned paper document,...) can be entered on some kind of mask and later retrieved using some kind of (keyword) search.

Ideally the software should send an email to tell a designated person that a contract would end in X weeks / months.

I was only able to find such functions as part of, for example, an IT management suit which also tracked assets, users, and much more. Obviously, this would be overkill...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm replying a bit late but I think you'll find my answer useful. [Agiloft](https://www.agiloft.com/) Contract Management Suite will do exactly what you're looking for. The [contract management software](https://www.agiloft.com/contract-management.htm) is built on a no-code platform that enables the solution to be tailored to your exact needs regarding storing and retrieving and contract notifications. The solution is capable of handling virtually any document including [procurement contracts](https://www.agiloft.com/procurement-clm.htm), HR, and from software vendors.

Answer (score 0):

Started working with Contractify back when corona lockdowns started, and honestly couldn't do without it anymore now. It's an online platform that helps you centralize, digitally sign & follow up contracts, including automatic notifications to colleagues who need to be aware of a contract ending, or needing any other action. User experience is fluent and finally have a clear overview of all contracts & what to do with them at any time... online :D The company behind the software also offers contract management services, where they just register & manage contracts for you. Thinking of looking into that option as well as they really seem to know how to best handle contracts & their customer support is superb :) Here's the link to their website I found online: https://www.contractify.io/ Hope this helps!